# How do I disable the button on the Vue?

Tags: vue.js, button

I want to disable/activate when I click on the Vue button, but I think I can't change the value to the method when I click because I'm already using emit. What should I do?

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h3>Child :</h3>
    <button type="button" :disabled="val" @click="$emit('send', yellow)">yellow</button>
    <button type="button" :disabled="!green" @click="$emit('send', green)">green</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Child",
  data(){
      return {yellow: "#ffa",green: "#bfb", val: true }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
div { border: 1px solid gray; padding: 10px; margin: 10px;  width:400px}
button { padding: 0.5em 1.5em; margin-right: 10px;}
</style>
```

Comment: If you need more functionality in the `@click` event handler, you could move the `$emit` [into a method](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Method-Event-Handlers), and call the method from `@click`.

Answer (score 0):

You can still do both things
Instead of using emit directly in the @click event binding, you could use a method instead

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h3>Child :</h3>
    <button type="button" :disabled="val" @click="handleClick">yellow</button>
    <button type="button" :disabled="!green" @click="$emit('send', green)">green</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Child",
  data(){
      return {yellow: "#ffa",green: "#bfb", val: true }
  }, 
  methods:{
    handleClick(){
      this.val=false;
      this.$emit('send', this.yellow);
   },
 }, 
}
</script>
```